# How To Select Row in JList Where Each Cell Contains JPanel that contains JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jlist

My code is currently written this way below as my intention was to wrap text inside each cell of JList. 
Now that part is successful with JTextArea in Panel rendered by JList, but I have a different issue.
I cannot seem to get each row selectable like a simple JList implementation.

How could I get make each row to be selectable? or Would you suggest to use a different component to wrap texts inside JList?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JListPractice3 {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JListPractice3();
        }
    });
}

public JListPractice3() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JList Practice");
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel listPanel = this.buildJListPanel();

    f.add(listPanel);

    f.pack();
}

/**
 * Build JList panel
 * @return JPanel
 */
private JPanel buildJListPanel() {
    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JList jList = new JList(getData());
    jList.setVisibleRowCount(1);
    jList.setFixedCellHeight(50);
    jList.setFixedCellWidth(250);
    jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().setView(jList);
    listPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    return listPanel;
}

/**
 * Get Alias data
 * @return String[]
 */
private String[] getData() {
    //TODO: remove hard code
    String[] data = {"123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
            + "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012",
            "two two two two two two two two two two two twotwo two two two two two two two two two two twotwo two two end",
            "two two two two two two two two two two two twotwo two two two two two two two end",
            "five", "six"};
    return data;
}

private class MyCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
    private JPanel p;
    private JPanel linePanel;
    private JLabel lineLabel;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MyCellRenderer() {
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        linePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        linePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 3));
        lineLabel = new JLabel("Test");
        linePanel.add(lineLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(linePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        p.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list,
            final Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected,
            final boolean hasFocus) {

        textArea.setText((String) value);
        int width = list.getWidth();
        // this is just to lure the ta's internal sizing mechanism into action
        if (width > 0) {
            textArea.setSize(width, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        return p;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the interface ListCellRender you must implement all effect, so for clarification the ListCellRender is an Component (an example JLabel) for setting the value and the all Listener (In this case you have add the listener inside the Component)

So in the your solution the component is selectionable but the your code not paint it, an my implementation of the you CellRender

```
private class MyCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements ListCellRenderer{
    private JPanel p;
    private JPanel linePanel;
    private JLabel lineLabel;

    public MyCellRenderer() {
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        linePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        linePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 3));
        lineLabel = new JLabel("Test");
        linePanel.add(lineLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(linePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        this.setLineWrap(true);
        this.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        p.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list,
            final Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected,
            final boolean hasFocus) {
        if(isSelected){
            this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }else{
            this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }
        this.setText((String) value);
        int width = list.getWidth();
        // this is just to lure the ta's internal sizing mechanism into action
        if (width > 0) {
            this.setSize(width, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        return this;
    }
  }
```

The result is

[image]

> How could I get make each row to be selectable? or Would you suggest to use a different component to wrap texts inside JList?

for responding to our request, my response is **depends**

If you have need only the visive effect I think this is a good solution, The `DefaultListCellRenderer` not managed the multiple lines.